# Basic Angular 6 app not showing bound variable

Tags: angular

After using Angular CLI to create a new project, followed by changing the app.component.html to this example code from w3schools:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>First name: {{firstname}}</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "John";
    $scope.lastname = "Doe";    
});
</script>

<p>You can use double braces to display content from the data model.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I do not get the expected names John Doe showing up, instead the fields are empty. I feel like I am mixing 2 things, but could not figure out what I am doing wrong. How do I get the bound variables to show up using in an Angular CLI project?

Comment: That code is from AngularJS (i.e. v1), not Angular (i.e. 2+)

Comment: Move script tag with angular code befor div with name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is from AngularJS.

Angular6 or just Angular is new version and is completly different framework.
Here is link,how to start: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Here are some explanation differences between Angular and AngularJS:

https://www.simplilearn.com/angularjs-vs-angular-2-vs-angular-4-differences-article